# How to select random elements from row sequentially from matrix but if the all elements in row selected don't select the same row again

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

let say i have this matrix

m =

```
 3     1     2     4     6     5
 2     3     5     6     1     4
 3     4     6     1     2     5
 2     1     3     4     5     6
 3     2     5     6     1     4
 2     4     6     1     5     3
```

which have 6 raw's and 6 column

i want to select randomly froms raw sequentially the first selection will choose the first

element in that raw

so if by random after covering all the elements in raw 5 i don't want the program to come

to select from it again

example if random iteration 1 select raw1 it will go to the first element in raw1 which is

in column 1

if by random in iteration 2 it select the same raw1 again it will select the the second

element in raw1 which is in column 2

so if i reached column 6 in raw1 and after it the iteration selected raw1 again but my

matrix is 6 column so i want to select by random another raw which is not reached till the

sixth column

let say if each time a raw is selected i will make a value in that column which equal to

one

so if i run 20 iterations

JM =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     0     0
```

by luck i didn't reach the sixth column in any of the raws

but if

JM =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0
```

**Attempted to access m(5,7); index out of bounds because size(m)=[6,6].**

how to continue random selection without coming to that raw which already full filled like

that raw 4 is already full filled

i hope it is easy to understand

iam using this method to create chromosome

which is in the form

m raw colmun =machine job operation

thanks

iam using matlab

Comment: What language? [tag:matlab]? [tag:rstats]?

Answer (score 0):

I can see three slightly different methods to achieve this.
You should create an array of integers to store the information containing amount of elements you already took from each raw. Lets assume your matrix is `[n*n]` so the array will be `[n]`. Lets call it `a[n]`

first method:

1. Generate random raw number `rNumber`.
2. Check if you can take elements from this raw ( `if(rNumber] < n)` ). If you can't take an element then go to (1). Otherwise continue to (3)
3. Take an element `m[rNumber][a[rNumber]]` and increment `a[rNumber]`

second method:

1. Generate random raw number `rNumber`.
2. Check if you can take elements from this raw ( `if(rNumber] < n)` )
3. If you can't take an element then go to increment `rNumber` and go to (2). Otherwise continue to (4)
4. Take an element `m[rNumber][a[rNumber]]` and increment `a[rNumber]`

The last method also need to store the amount of raws where you took all the elements `rawCount`.

1. Generate random raw number `rNumber` between `0` and `n-rawCount-1`
2. Enumerate through all raws while `currentRaw < rNumber`. If `a[currentRaw] < n` then increment `currentRaw`
3. Take an element `m[currentRaw][a[currentRaw]]` and increment `a[currentRaw]`
4. If `a[currentRaw] = n` then increment `rawCount`

Answer (score 0):

here is something that i wrote in c++. hope this is what were you looking for. don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand something

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("stack2.in");
ofstream g("stack2.out");
int a[10][10]; 
int solution[100],n,m,index =0; 

void build(int n,int m)//create a MxN matrix, and fill it with values
{
    int zz = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {

            a[i][j]= zz;
            zz++;
        }

}

void solve()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int i,j;//column and line
    while(index<m*n)
    {

        i = (rand()%10);//get random values for column and line
        j = (rand()%10);

        if(a[i][j]!=0) //if the value of matrix[i][j] is not 0, means that this value is new, so we add it to the solution list
        {
            solution[index]=a[i][j];
            index++; 
            a[i][j]=0; //set the value from matrix[i][j] to 0 so we don't 'visit' again
        }

        else if(i<=n) //if the value from the matrix[i][j] is equal to 0, we start searching on the line of of i for values that are not 0
        {
            while(j<m)
            {
                if(a[i][j+1]!=0) //if matrix[i][j+1] has not been visited before, we add it to the solution, set it to zero and exit the while
                {
                    solution[index]= a[i][j+1];
                    a[i][j+1]=0;
                    index++;
                    j=m; //exit the while


                }
                else
                    j++; //keep searching for a value on that line
            }
        }   
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=m*n;i++)//print the list with random values
        g<<solution[i]<<" ";

}


int main()
{
    n=10;//or read the values from stack2.in using f>>n>>m 
    m=10;//in the file should be written on the same line, number of lines and columens of the matrix eg.: 5 7
    build(n,m);
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can set it as solution :)